# How to Close Fancybox with a Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I need the ability for Fancybox to be closed when a user clicks a link inside the fancybox.

I have tried:
`href="javascript:$j.fn.fancybox.close();"`
(note I am using jQuery with no conflict hence the $j) `

When I try it it does not work and I get an error in Firebug that says  `$j.fn.fancybox.close is not a function.`

Note: I am using Fancybox version 1.3.4

Here is the script of the Fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function(){

      $j("#start").fancybox({

    'padding' : 0
});

</script>
```

HTML Code for Fancybox:

```
<div class="hide">
    <img src="/Images/skin/spacer1x1.png" onload="$j('#start').trigger('click');" />  
<a href="#welcome" id="start"></a>
    <img style="width:700px; height:600px;" id="welcome" usemap="#Map" alt="PLEASE VIEW PAGE WITH IMAGES ON" src="/Images/start/start.png" />
    <map id="Map" name="Map">
    <area alt="See Message Examples" href="/artistphotos/" coords="29,431,301,465" shape="rect" />
    <area alt="Enter Site" href="javascript:$j.fn.fancybox.close();" coords="436,433,567,464" shape="rect" />
    </map>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try calling `$j.fancybox.close();` rather than `$j.fn.fancybox.close();`

Answer (score 12):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="window.parent.parent.location.reload();">Close this</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`$.fancybox.close();`

---

And if you are trying to **close fancybox from inside an iframe** try this:

`window.parent.$.fancybox.close();`

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.

[How to open links from inframe outside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193839/how-to-open-links-from-inframe-outside-of-it)

Seems like the `target="_top"` does the job!