# How to open links from inframe outside of it?

Tags: html, iframe, lightbox

well I have that problem, im using a lightbox srcipt and im opening an iframe in it so it's simply iframe. Is there a way to put a link inside of this iframe and open this link in normal window (outside of iframe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<a href="..." target="_top">My Link</a>`to put it on top of all other frames (break out).

_blank will put in a new window or tab

_parent will put the link in the frame above the current (same as _top if only one level of frame)

Using the name (not id) of a frame will open the link in that frame.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target="_parent"` to the link tag, to open the link in the parent page that contains the IFrame, or `target="_blank`, to open the link in a new browser window.

```
target="_blank"       New window
target="_self"        Current window
target="_parent"      Parent frame
target="_top"         Full browser window
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the link in a new window/tab, use the `_blank` target:

```
<a href="someurl..." target="_blank">
```

If you want to open the link so that it replaces the page where the iframe is, use the `_top` target:

```
<a href="someurl..." target="_top">
```